# How to cache an augmented dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataframe that I increase it in each transformation, I need to optimize the execution 
time. My question is to make a cache() after each transformation?

```
partitions=100
df = df.repartition(partitions, "uuid").cache()

df_aug = tran_1(df).cache()
df_aug = tran_2(df_aug).cache()
.
.
df_aug = tran_n(df_aug)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is not a magic bullet to improve performance - in you scenario it will likely slow everything down. 
It's a good idea to use caching when you access the same dataset multiple times (e.g. in data exploration). If you do multiple transformations on a single dataset it will cause serialization and storage while it will be read only once.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can't cache an updated dataframe (Spark isn't as smart to update the memory) Right?

Comment: You can cache an updated dataframe, but this will not improve your performance. The best way to improve your performance is to see if you can rewrite your transformation functions to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
The data will be cached only after an action.
And you are performing cache after all transformations.
This is not required. You can use  cache after first transformation.
Then apply a small action. Then use cached data  in subsequent transformations.

df.cache()
df.count()
df_aug = tran_1(df)
df_aug = tran_2(df_aug)

This approach will be more optimized.
```